# Subscribe in live query in background | Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am making a objective c app that will be running on the parse open source platform. I want to use the [live query](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery) but I am not sure how. Is there a way I could subscribe a user to a certain channel and they could get a local notification when a new object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live query is only available on Parse server and not on Parse.com

in case you are using Your own Parse Server

You can enable live query like this

First you have to setup live query in your parse server

```
let api = new ParseServer({...,liveQuery: {
classNames: ['Player']}});
```

Then, it just takes a few lines of code to create the LiveQuery server:

```
 // app is the Parse Server instance 
 let httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
 httpServer.listen(port);
 ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Hope helps.